# Hibernate Session's data in stored procedure

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a simple question. Is there ability to get the data from hibernate session in stored procedure? It looks like:

```
@Transactional
public void doAction() {
    Product pr = new Product("Apple");
    hibernateTemplate.save(product);
    executeStoredProcedure();
    hibernateTemplate.save(new Product("foobar"));
}
```

executeStoredProcedure - method executes the stored procedure via JDBC. This stored procedure must hava access to created product (Apple).

Also, all actions with db should be executed in one transaction.

How i can to implement something similar to this?

Oracle DB is used (PLSQL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling [`flush()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html#flush%28%29) before invoking the stored procedure in order to have the new product synced to the database.

Quote from the javadoc of flush():

> Only invoke this for selective eager flushing, for example when JDBC code needs to see certain changes within the same transaction.

...which is exactly what you need, I think.